# Remove rows from Pandas dataframe where value only appears once

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with monthly records for different IDs, and I need to do some analysis only on the IDs that have multiple months of records.

```
ID    Month       Metric1    Metric2
1     2018-01-01  4          3      
1     2018-02-01  3          2
2     2018-02-01  1          5
3     2018-01-01  4          2
3     2018-02-01  6          3
4     2018-01-01  3          1
```

How would I filter out the rows of ID that only appear once and keep those with multiple rows and get a result like

```
ID    Month       Metric1    Metric2
1     2018-01-01  4          3      
1     2018-02-01  3          2
3     2018-01-01  4          2
3     2018-02-01  6          3
```

I've looked at some other pages that mention using something like:

```
df = df[df.groupby('ID').ID.transform(len) > 1]
```

But I don't want to lose the metrics from each month by grouping.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change the `len` to `count`

```
df[df.groupby('ID').ID.transform('count') > 1]
Out[589]: 
   ID       Month  Metric1  Metric2
0   1  2018-01-01        4        3
1   1  2018-02-01        3        2
3   3  2018-01-01        4        2
4   3  2018-02-01        6        3
```

Comment: This answer is nice because it's flexible; we can also select on other frequencies or frequency ranges.

Answer (score 6):

Try with [`pd.series.duplicated()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df1=df[df.ID.duplicated(keep=False)]
print(df1)
```

---

```
   ID       Month  Metric1  Metric2
0   1  2018-01-01        4        3
1   1  2018-02-01        3        2
3   3  2018-01-01        4        2
4   3  2018-02-01        6        3
```

Comment: I'd say this answer is a bit simpler/cleaner than @BENY's answer.

Answer (score 3):

#### [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html)

I cannot vouche for the speed of this **but** this is what this API was intended for...

```
df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda d: len(d) > 1)

   ID       Month  Metric1  Metric2
0   1  2018-01-01        4        3
1   1  2018-02-01        3        2
3   3  2018-01-01        4        2
4   3  2018-02-01        6        3
```

---

Numpy'd version of @Wen-Ben's answer

```
u, i = np.unique(df.ID.values, return_inverse=True)

df[np.bincount(i)[i] > 1]

   ID       Month  Metric1  Metric2
0   1  2018-01-01        4        3
1   1  2018-02-01        3        2
3   3  2018-01-01        4        2
4   3  2018-02-01        6        3
```

---

Because I was curious...

```
s0 = set()
s1 = set()

for i in df.ID:
    if i in s0:
        s1.add(i)
    s0.add(i)

df[df.ID.map(s1.__contains__)]

   ID       Month  Metric1  Metric2
0   1  2018-01-01        4        3
1   1  2018-02-01        3        2
3   3  2018-01-01        4        2
4   3  2018-02-01        6        3
```