# Remove rows from PySpark dataframe where value only appears once

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, drop

There is a very similar question to this one for [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55871521/remove-rows-from-pandas-dataframe-where-value-only-appears-once)

my Dataframe is like the following:

```
ID    Month   Metric1    Metric2
1       01       4          3
3       01       4          2
3       01       3          1      
1       02       3          2
1       02       1          5
2       02       6          3
2       02       7          2
3       03       5          6
```

I want to first group by Month and then by ID (for the dropping, the result should not be grouped). Lastly I would like to drop all rows whose id or month appears only once.

```
ID    Month   Metric1    Metric2
-       --       -          -
3       01       4          2
3       01       3          1      
1       02       3          2
1       02       1          5
2       02       6          3
2       02       7          2
-       --       -          -
```

so the same problem as the question I linked above, only in PySpark and with two groupings...

I have been trying to convert the pandas command into pyspark, but I don't know how to replace the [], as pyspark doesn't seem to know them...

```
df2 = df[df.groupBy("ID", "Month")].ID.count("ID") >1]
```

Also, I tried window functions. But they always end up needing am aggregation function and I don't want the data to be aggregated:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W
window = W.partitionBy("Month").orderBy("ID")
df.withColumn("ID",Moth.over(window)) \
    .show()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get counts partitioned by Id and Month and eliminate row having count as 1:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

w = W.partitionBy("ID","Month").orderBy("Month")
out = df.withColumn("C",F.count("ID").over(w)).filter("C!=1").drop("C")
```